# Creating and storing data in the database

Tags: database

I have created a forum in administer->modules in Drupal 6, and I have set the permissions also, but it is not showing in my site.
I do not know how the forum contents will be stored in database, and how to establish a connection to the database.

Comment: If you are using the Forum module, why do you need to know how the content is stored in the database?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to worry about the database. But do some reading on how the forum works. If you're not getting any error messages you probably didn't set it up correctly.

Visit this page to see a list of all your forums: `www.example.com/admin/content/forum/list`

And some reading:

- [The Drupal forum tutorial](http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-make-a-drupal-forum)
- [Forum: create threaded discussions](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/forum) - there are sub-menus depending on your version of Drupal

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have skipped some necessary steps for configuring Drupal 6 forums.

Forums are based on a taxonomy structure, which you'll first need to create in: /admin/content/forum
You create "containers" (where "forums" can be created) and forums (where topics can be created and replies made to them). This is a fairly good overview of all the steps needed to set up a basic forum system in Drupal 6: [E-how article for building forum website in Drupal 6](http://www.ehow.com/how_7419053_build-forum-website-drupal-6.html)

You may also wish to consider using the [Advanced forum module](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_forum), which adds some extra functionality to the fairly basic "core" forum features.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache in Drupal.
You don't need to manually connect to the database.